# Implication of closed diagonal in product space.

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, proof-writing

I have to prove (b) implies (c) in the following.

[image]

Here's my attempt to prove the [<=] direction of (c). I get stuck in one particular step listed out below.

Let $z \in Z$, $z \notin D$. Assume for a contradiction that $f_1(z) \neq f_2(z)$. Then $(f_1(z),f_2(z)) \notin \Delta(X)$. Since $\Delta(X)$ is closed, there exists an open set $U \in (X \times X), U \ni (f_1(z),f_2(z)) \ \text{s.t.} \ U \cap \Delta(X) = \emptyset$. Let $pr_1(U) = U_1, pr_2(U) = U_2$, where $pr_1$ and $pr_2$ are the projections from $(X \times X)$ to the first and second coordinates, respectively. Then $U_1 \cap U_2 = \emptyset$, since otherwise $U \cap \Delta(X) \neq \emptyset$, hence contradiction. Also $U_1 \ni f_1(z),\text{ and } U_2 \ni f_2(z)$.

It's here that I got stuck, since I need, but cannot prove the existence of, a set $V$open in $Z$, $V \ni z$, and $V \subset f_1^{-1}(U_1) \cap f_2^{-1}(U_2)$.

====================================================================

**Edit**: Next I'd have to show that (c) implies that X is Hausdorff. I'd like a hint for this direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So we have open $U,V$ in $X$ with $(f_1(z), f_2(z)) \in U \times V$ and $(U \times V) \cap \Delta(X)=\emptyset$. (You call $U$, $U_1$ and $V$, $U_2$)

This indeed implies $U \cap V = \emptyset$, as stated. So by continuity of $f_1$ and $f_2$ we have that $f_1^{-1}[U] \cap f_2^{-1}[V]$ is open and contains $z$, so is non-empty. Hence that set intersects the dense set $D$, and we have some

$$d \in D \cap f_1^{-1}[U] \cap f_2^{-1}[V]$$

and for this $d$ we have $f_1(d) \in U$, $f_2(d) \in V$ so $f_1(d) \neq f_2(d)$ (by the disjointness of $U$ and $V$) and this contradicts $f_1\restriction_D = f_2\restriction_D$.

Another, simpler, proof is the following: Note that $F:Z \to X \times X, F(x)=(f_1(x),f_2(x))$ is continuous whenever $f_1$ and $f_2$ are (as the composition with the projections are continuous). So assuming (b), $F^{-1}[\Delta(X)]$ is closed in $Z$ and by asssumption (if we do the backward implication again) contains $D$ and so $Z=\overline{D} \subseteq F^{-1}[\Delta(X)]$ which implies $f_1= f_2$.

Comment: But we're not given that $f_1$ and $f_2$ are continuous? If this is a typo, can you give a counterexample?

Comment: Next I'd have to show that (c) implies that X is Hausdorff. Can you give a hint for this direction?

Comment: Probably (a) is "$X$ is Hausdorff", and then it can be easier to show that not (a) impies not (c), (after (a) implies (b), so making them all equivalent in a circle) which is logically the same as (c) implies (a). In that case show that $X$ not being Hausdorff implies you can define a $Z$ and dense $D$ and two functions $f_1,f_2$ that contradict (c).

Comment: Can I take $Z = X \times X$, $D = \Delta$, and somehow prove that $\Delta$ is dense in $X \times X$?

Comment: @ensbana Try $Z=\overline{\Delta(X)}$, $f_1,f_2$ the projections and $D = \Delta(X)$ instead.

Comment: I've been trying but couldn't see why $Z \setminus D \neq \emptyset$.

Comment: @ensbana If $X$ is not Hausdorff, the diagonal is not closed, and so such a point must exist in the closure of $D$. Otherwise put: if $x \neq y$ cannot be separated by open sets, $(x,y) \in Z\setminus D$. (b) to (a) is not needed for that.

Comment: Hmmm, so I'd have to prove (b) => (a) first.